# Offset DataGridView Building in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I am currently trying to build a car race tracking program in Visual Basic to replace the old Excel method used currently. The program simply tracks four lanes, and is designed to build a race grid using information added or imported into a datagridview. The race grid needs to build a set that will run each car on each lane depending on the amount of heats. E.g. there is 2 heats, each car will need run each of the four lanes twice. The trouble I am having is developing code to assemble the data correctly into the grid. The simplest way to set up the grid is to have four columns, and each column over, the grid is offset by one.

For the code setup:
The info is taken from a datagridview named gridRacerInfo. Only columns 0 and 1 are needed. They are added together to make the name and the car number. The actual race grid, named gridRaceBuild contains 5 columns. The first column is taken care of by the code by setting the amount of races needed by the number of racers multiplied by the number of heats. The button to build the race grid is only activated after a minimum of four racers are added, but the program needs to support different combinations of racers and amount of heats. Some code I developed fills in the actual grid but does not offset the grid so each racer does not race each track based on the amount of heats.

[Example Grid](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7SpategDPkfdGtjTDJmSG1MR0E/edit?usp=sharing)

The grid should look like this to an extent. Minus the place column.

Some code I have tried:

```
        gridRaceBuild.RowCount = varNumberofRacers * NumberOfHeats.Value
    For varBuildGridColumns As Integer = 1 To 4
        For varBuildGridRows As Integer = 0 To varNumberofRacers * NumberOfHeats.Value - 1
            If varBuildShiftCatch Then
                gridRaceBuild.Item(varBuildGridColumns, varBuildGridRows).Value = gridRacerInfo.Item(0, varBuildGridRows + varBuildShift).Value & " - " & gridRacerInfo.Item(1, varBuildGridRows).Value
        Next varBuildGridRows
        If varBuildShift < 0 Then
            varBuildShift = varBuildShift + 1
        End If
        If varBuildShift = 5 Then
            varBuildShift = 0
        End If
    Next varBuildGridColumns
```

Any help would be great.
Thank you in advance,
Nate

*Edit*
As commented, adding code that has work and not worked.

I have tried to set IF and THEN traps such as Case traps.

This code will build the table with no errors. Although it does not offset the racers like it should.
For example if there are four racers with car numbers 1 through 4 the heats look like this:
Heat 1: Car 1 | Car 1 | Car 1 | Car 1 |
Heat 2: Car 2 | Car 2 | Car 2 | Car 2 | 
... 
when it should be

Heat 1: Car 1 | Car 2 | Car 3 | Car 4 |
Heat 2: Car 2 | Car 3 | Car 4 | Car 1 |
...

So simply put I need the selection to wrap around so the cars run each track. The other catch I have with the code is that if needed, each car must run the track more than once. This will also double the size of the race grid.

```
 gridRaceBuild.RowCount = varNumberofRacers * NumberOfHeats.Value
    For varBuildGridColumns As Integer = 1 To 4
        For varBuildGridRows As Integer = 0 To varNumberofRacers * NumberOfHeats.Value - 1
                gridRaceBuild.Item(varBuildGridColumns, varBuildGridRows).Value = gridRacerInfo.Item(0, varBuildGridRows + varBuildShift).Value & " - " & gridRacerInfo.Item(1, varBuildGridRows).Value
        Next varBuildGridRows
    Next varBuildGridColumns
```

This code takes car of the size of the table based on how many times the cars need to run each lane:

```
gridRaceBuild.RowCount = varNumberofRacers * NumberOfHeats.Value
```

#### Update

I have developed some code that will perfectly create the first two rows of the race grid.

```
gridRaceBuild.RowCount = varNumberofRacers
    For varBuildGridColumns As Integer = 1 To 4
        varBuildShiftCatch = True
        For varBuildGridRows As Integer = 0 To varNumberofRacers - 1
            Select Case varBuildGridColumns
                Case 1
                    gridRaceBuild.Item(varBuildGridColumns, varBuildGridRows).Value = gridRacerInfo.Item(0, varBuildGridRows).Value & " - " & gridRacerInfo.Item(1, varBuildGridRows).Value
                Case 2
                    varBuildShift = 1
                    If varBuildShiftCatch = True Then
                        If varBuildGridRows = varNumberofRacers - 2 Then
                            varBuildShiftCatch = False
                        End If
                        gridRaceBuild.Item(varBuildGridColumns, varBuildGridRows).Value = gridRacerInfo.Item(0, varBuildGridRows + varBuildShift).Value & " - " & gridRacerInfo.Item(1, varBuildGridRows + varBuildShift).Value
                    Else
                        gridRaceBuild.Item(varBuildGridColumns, varBuildGridRows).Value = gridRacerInfo.Item(0, varBuildGridRows - (varNumberofRacers - 1)).Value & " - " & gridRacerInfo.Item(1, varBuildGridRows - (varNumberofRacers - 1)).Value
                    End If
```

This section of code will create the first two columns of the race grid. Properly offsetting the cars by one as shown in the link above. Turns out I was adding each time to the variable that was telling the program to offset the cars by one, when it should have been static. The issue is that when the code is introduced into the next column, it leaves a blank cell on the grid and is not offsetting the cars properly again. I have tried changing many of the variables contained within the code but they all yield errors.

Comment: You show code you have tried, which is a good start. How about adding details about what is working and what is not? You will get answers for specific questions, but broad questions like this are hard to answer in this forum.

Comment: Okay. I can do that. I tried to be much more specific than one line questions. I see those all the time around here.